# How do I expose a variable from a class in Unreal Engine 4 to blueprints?

Tags: unreal-4

I would like to expose to blueprints the variable [CurrentTouchInterface](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/GameFramework/APlayerController/CurrentTouchInterface/index.html) in the class APlayerController, just like the method [APlayerController::ActivateTouchInterface](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/GameFramework/APlayerController/ActivateTouchInterface/index.html).

So, I'm guessing I have to change the header file **PlayerController.h** from this

```
/** The currently set touch interface */
UPROPERTY()
class UTouchInterface* CurrentTouchInterface;
```

To something like this

```
/** The currently set touch interface */
UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadOnly, Category="Game|Player")
class UTouchInterface* CurrentTouchInterface;
```

The point is, what do I need to do for the engine's editor to start showing the exposed variable `CurrentTouchInterface` in blueprints?

I'm working with UE 4.9 downloaded from the Epic Games Launcher application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not compiling the Unreal Engine source code, any changes you make in the `PlayerController.h` file will be ignored. If you are prepared to modify the source, you can do the step you outlined in your question and compile the editor. You can [read more about compiling the editor on the Unreal website](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/Development/BuildingUnrealEngine/index.html).

However, it would be easier (and probably cleaner as you won't be running a custom version of Unreal), to create a helper function that takes a player controller and gets the current touch interface. Something like this (inside any class will do, but I like to have a class just for static blueprint functions):

```
UFUNCTION(BlueprintPure, Category = "Game|Player")
static class UTouchInterface* GetPlayerCurrentTouchInterface(APlayerController* Controller);
```

Then the implementation would just be:

```
return Controller->CurrentTouchInterface;
```

In the blueprint editor, you will be able to drag out from a player controller variable and get this node.

Comment: Ok, I'll try something like [this](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Custom_Blueprint_Node_Creation), by the way, do you know where do I have to put those new clases in the project folder on a Mac?

Comment: I imagine in the `Source/ProjectName/` folder (but I'm on Windows). However, in the editor there is a command to create a new class. It can be reached from "File>New C++ Class". This will generate the files in the right place with some required boilerplate code. It doesn't matter what you derive from since your functions are static, but I use `UBlueprintFunctionLibrary` to make its purpose clear.